# Edit scheduled message from a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

right now in my view I have my future messages displaying in a table, which is great but now I want the admin to have the option to edit or delete. How can I place in that same view a edit and delete button that is operational.
Here is my code and view right now.

```
def schedule_message
    @message = Message.where(["send_at >= ?", Time.zone.now])
end
```

here is my html

```
<tbody>
    <% @message.each do |message| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= message.body %></td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

here is my view.

[image]

Comment: you may add the routes to your views directly to edit/update views.what more do you want...is it what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, you have set up your **edit** and **delete** paths in your routes and as well you have controller and actions in place.

```
<tbody>
 <% @message.each do |message| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= message.body %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', message_path(message),method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
</tbody>
```